# My interface not working - Variable boolean receives string

Tags: angular, typescript

Typescript does not generate an error when I assign a string value to a boolean variable.

I forced an error to see how the typescript behaved and it did not generate the error that I expected.

I created a class with an attribute of type boolean. Then I created an interface. And I created the constructor method to initialize the variable.So I get a json where the variable is of type string. To my surprise the boolean variable receives the string. I wish it would generate an error. My code does not respect the type of the variable.

```
export class Product{

    public status:boolean;

    constructor(obj?: IProduct) { 

        if(obj)
        {
            this.status = obj.status;
        }
    }

}

interface IProduct {
    status:boolean;
}
```

my json of server

```
{status: "test"}
```

The test value is assigned to the status variable. And this should not be allowed.

Does anyone know how I can ensure that the variable only receives boolean value?

Comment: nome or status?

Comment: There is no "status" attribute in the interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no type enforcement at runtime.

[Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) (an experimental feature) may solve your problem:

```ts
class Product {
    @validate
    public status: boolean;

    constructor(obj?: IProduct) { 
        if(obj) {
            this.status = obj.status;
        }
    }
}

interface IProduct {
    status: string;
}

function validate(target: any, propertyKey: string) : any {
    if (propertyKey === "status") {
        return {
            set: function (value: any) {
                if (typeof value !== "boolean") {
                    throw new Error("The supplied value is not of type boolean");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're right. There appears to be no runtime type checking

Comment: The question I have is: porque usar tipagem if typescript does not handle type at runtime. Typescript does not take into account the types of data coming from the server

Comment: Runtime type enforcement [is not in the TypeScript Design Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#goals). Have a look at [this issue and the discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1573).

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with you Interface

```
interface IProduto { // typo it should be IProduct
    nome:boolean; // and this should be name i suppose but i left it nome
}
```

And If you want to ensure that all values must have specified types you can set **noImplicitAny** to true in **tsconfig.json**,implies to TS Classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
interface IProduct {
    status: Boolean;
}
```

notice the interface typo and change nome to status.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if statement in your constructor:

```
if (typeof obj !== 'boolean') {
    throw Error('type of obj must be boolean');
}
```